# How to move folder between team project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have created two team projects (`Demo` and `NewTest`) in my collection (`DemoCode`). I accidentially mapped my application (`WindowsFormsApplication3`) to the wrong team project (`Demo`):

[image]

How can I move the above application (`WindowsFormsApplication3`) to the correct team project (`NewTest`).

Here is what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just right click, select move, and specify the location that you want.

Caveat: This does a branch+delete under the covers.

Caveat#2: You need to have latest for both locations in the same workspace.

Comment: When I right click on the folder, I don't see a move option.

Comment: Actually I do see it, but Move and Rename are disabled and cannot be selected.

Comment: You need to have latest in the same workspace for both locations.

Comment: I am new to TFS so I am not sure what you mean. I right clicked on it and checked the project in.

Comment: So what I did was, I had to create a new project and added it to new team project and then I had to drill down to the sub folder for WindowsFormApplication3 and then move it to the new collection with the new project folder. The issue is, I now have an extra project which I don't need.